# How to synchronize refresh relationships after removing associated object?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

Class `Car` has a 1:n-relationship to `Feature`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="car", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Feature> features;
```

The representation in Class `Feature` looks like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Car car;
```

When I pass one `Feature`-object associated with a certain `Car`-Object to `DatabaseService#delete()` it will successfully be removed from database but still be in the `Car`-Objects feature list.

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
public class DatabaseService implements Serializable {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void delete(Object o) {
        o = em.merge(o);
        em.remove(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to do that generic in the `DatabaseService.delete()` method? The deleted `Feature` instance will be in the list of which `Car` instance (do you have one in a session)?

Comment: @AndreiI Yes, I have one `Car`-instance in a session. I want to reuse `delete()` for alike cases of other objects with relationships.

Comment: And the problem is that the `Car` instance from session contains the deleted `Feature` instance?

Comment: Well, you will have to refetch your car completely from DB. Usually you keep in sessions objects that you know when to synchronize.

Comment: @AndreiI "Usually you keep in sessions objects that you know when to synchronize." I don't understand.

Comment: Suppose you have webSession1 with the car instance in it and websession2 that deletes the feature instance. WebSession1 will not know when to refetch the car from DB.

Answer (score 0):

Do not call the database operation on Feature. Set the cascade property on the collection, remove the feature from the Car and then persist car. Then the in-memory model and database are in synch.

```
public class Car {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "car", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Feature> features;

    public void removeFeature(Feature feature) {
        features.remove(feature);
        feature.setCar(null);
    }

    public void addFeature(Feature feature){
        features.add(feature);
        feature.setCar(this);
    }
}
```